# set property and on_done method

Tags: python, sublimetext2

In this python code for a sublimetext plugin:

```
class PersonCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        self.name = None
        self.view.window().show_input_panel("Name", "", self.on_done, None, None)
        print "run: ", self.name

    def on_done(self, value):
        self.name = value
        print "on_done: ", self.name
```

if I enter "Jack" in the input panel I would expect

```
run: Jack
```

however I *actually* get:

```
run: None
on_done: Jack
```

Why do I get this result? Can I use the input panel as a prompt to read arguments and if so, how?

Comment: What output did you expect, and why is this a problem?

Comment: The self refers to the object and any method could change the proprieties why the on_done don't ?

Comment: What do you mean "the on_done don't"? It looks like the value does get changed (thus "on_done: Jack"). What does the first line have to do with this?

Comment: I am new to python , but I think that the order of execution imply that the name is none, then we enter a name , then on_done called the name is Jack , so the print "run: ", self.name should print last value Jack !! If I am wrong explain to me please thx,

Comment: The `run` function clearly happens *before* the `on_done` function. The value is set by the line `self.name = value` in the `on_done` function, so naturally that line is executed after the `run` function. (However, could you point me towards the instructions for the `on_done` method? I haven't been able to find them).

Comment: The documentation of SublimeText2 is not well documented API reference: http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html#sublime.Window , the show_input_panel obiously shows an input when enter is pressed it calls on_done with the value from the input

Comment: Right, understood. See answer below. (Also, why is this a problem?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the `on_done` function is a callback. When this line runs:

```
    self.view.window().show_input_panel("Name", "", self.on_done, None, None)
```

it *doesn't call on_done immediately*. The function just sets up `self.on_done` as the method that will be called once a value is entered. That means the line afterwards, `print "run: ", self.name`, will occur before any value is entered.

The function `on_done` occurs later (it could be seconds or minutes later, depending on when the user enters a value). Only then does the value get set and the `print "on_done: ", self.name` statement occurs.

Comment: I checked a lot of codes they always use self.view.window().show_input_panel(...) at the end of the run , thanks a lot